# Why isn't tk.IntVar working for the second tk window?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.3, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to use tk.Scale to change a tk.IntVar. I can do it on the first tk window but I can't on the second one. Why?

Look this poor sample:

```
import tkinter as tk

# main root
root = tk.Tk()

myvar = tk.IntVar()

def on_change(*args):
   print("Value changed to {}".format(myvar.get())) 

myvar.trace("w", on_change)

sc = tk.Scale(root, from_=1, to=10, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=320, \
    variable=myvar)
sc.grid()

# second root
root2 = tk.Tk()

myvar2 = tk.IntVar()

def on_change2(*args):
   print("Value2 changed to {}".format(myvar2.get())) 

myvar2.trace("w", on_change2)

sc2 = tk.Scale(root2, from_=1, to=10, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, length=320, \
    variable=myvar2)
sc2.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

What am I doing wrong?
I'm using python 3.3 on Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot have two instances of `tkinter.Tk` running simultaneously in the same thread. They will not share the Tcl interpreter properly and the one that was created first will always act as the main window.

To fix the problem, make `root2` an instance of [`tkinter.Toplevel`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm):

```
root2 = tk.Toplevel()
```

The `tkinter.Toplevel` window will be dependent on the `tkinter.Tk` one, which means it will share the Tcl interpreter started for the latter.